# starting neo4j server became slow after batchinsert modification

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a question about creating a new/modifying an existing big database in Neo4j Java API. 
Previously, I've tried to modify the label of each node in a database by using straightforward approaches which was really time consuming. 
I've found a solution for that which is "BatchInserter".

```
config.put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "50000M");
    db = BatchInserters.inserter("dblp.db", config);
    BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(db);
    index = indexProvider.nodeIndex("dblpIndex", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
    index.setCacheCapacity(URI_PROPERTY, 500000001);

if ((totalEntity % 50000) == 0) {
            System.out.println("entities: " + totalEntity);
            index.flush();
        }
```

It was very fast to create/modify the database by this method. However, after this, when I want to use this database in Java/Cypher API, it takes lots of time to start. 
I think it should be related to some index things! But I don't know how I can fix it. Could you please guide me on this?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

- I don't run any query, and it takes time at starting time either with server or java API.
- I have another database which is really fast at start time. I've compared their message.log

Slower one bottleneck is:

> 2016-02-03 22:**25**:54.730+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
>
> 2016-02-03 22:**28**:18.408+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.KernelHealth] Kernel
>   health set to OK

It takes **three minutes** after this line of message.log

However, for the faster one with same amount of volume on the disk:

> 2016-02-03 22:30:**28**.254+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
>
> 2016-02-03 22:30:**43**.380+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.KernelHealth] Kernel
>   health set to OK

it takes just couple of seconds.

---

I've checked the inserting code. I had `db.shutdown()` at the end of the program, and I recalled that it was more time/memory consuming part.

The last thing which might be helpful is: for the faster one I can see some lucene node index initialization (e.g. _0.fdt: 2015-12-23T12:52:33-0800 - 143.00 B, _1.fdx: 2015-12-23T12:53:13-0800 - 3.81 MB) in the message.log but there isn't anything like this in the slower one message.log file and also in its corresponding directory (database.db/index/lucene/node/)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean that it takes some time to start the database server, or that the Cypher queries are slow to execute? What is the query?

Comment: I mean starting the server takes time, or this line of code in java (new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(MODELGRAPH_DB_PATH);). If you have any question for making it clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Suspicion: you didn't call [`BatchInserter.shutdown()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/unsafe/batchinsert/BatchInserter.html#shutdown()) ?

It's crucial to explicitly shutdown batchinserter. If not, starting up the datastore will lead to sanity checks upon startup (best case) or a unusable datastore (not so best case).

Comment: I've checked the inserting code. I had db.shutdown() at the end of the program, and I recalled that it was more time/memory consuming part. I've added some clarification. Could you please check it again?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you use the latest version?

Did you create any indexes / constraints as part of your insertion?

Otherwise for the initial start-up,

- the count-store (statistics),
- label-scan-store (inverse-lookup) and
- indexes / constraints

will be created.

Also you will want to set `dbms.pagecache.memory` at least for recent versions that's what you use instead of `neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory`.

Otherwise it might help to share your `graph.db/messages.log` file for analysis of your setup/config.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the neo4j-2.3.0.jar and I think it should be the latest one. I didn't add any other things. just flush() every 50K and finally shutdown the batchinserter. How should I do these things you mentioned above?